# UIImageView won't resize with image

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, ios8.3

This one is driving me crazy. I have an `UIImageView` with the constraint 'width <= 34'. When I set the image to `nil` I expect the view's width to shrink to zero, but it won't.

I've double and triple checked everything... no other constraints that should interfere, etc. In fact, I have another table view cell where this works perfectly.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** Here are all the constraints for this view.

[image][image]

Comment: What are _all_ the constraints affecting this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Height width inequalities for view without intrinsic content size creates ambiguous layouts.**
(To be exact, for views that return `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` as height and width in intrinsic content size)

Lets understand this. In the below image every thing looks right.

[image]

Now, when the image is set to nil, auto layout alerts us about ambiguity.
Why? Because without image, returned intrinsic height and width are `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` and then inequalities like "height <= 37" alone cannot help the auto layout engine to find the height/width of the view.

[image: A UIIMageView with no content image, alerts about ambiguous layout]

Now when we set explicit intrinsic content size(not applicable on runtime though), the ambiguity is resolved.

[image: Same UIImageView when set with intrinsic size placeholder resolves ambiguity]

So, to solve your problem we need to return 0,0 as intrinsic content size.
You should try subclassing UIImageView that overrides `-intrinsicContentSize`.

```
@implementation ZeroedIntrinsicContentSizeImageView

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    if (self.image)
        return [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return CGSizeZero;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, implementing intrinsicContentSize and returning (2.0, 2.0) I've noticed that there must be an additional issue since the image will now shrink in height but not in width. So I'm starting to suspect that the UIImageView now behaves as expected but the adjacent UITextView is not expanding when it should. I'll report back and accept your answer after some more extensive testing.

Comment: Still Struggling? Here is a sample

Comment: It works now as expected! Thanks. The thing that was required in addition to implementing intrinsicContentSize in my case, was to give the adjacent text label a content hugging priority of < 250. Otherwise it would not expand to the left.